# How to find the minimum area?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, problem-solving

I am trying to solve the following problem, using functions and the application of derivatives to find maximums and minimums:

> A wire of $L$ length is cut in two parts. The first one is used to form a square, and the second one to form a circumference. How should the wire be cut so that the sum of the two areas is minimum?

Considering that each side of the square is $x$, and $L$ the complete length of the wire, I was thinking of using two functions:
$$f\left(x\right):\:A=x^2+\pi r^2$$
$$f\left(x\right):\:L=4x+2\pi r$$
The issue is that I am not sure how to solve this, considering that the functions I made are good in the first place.

Comment: To proceed one step forward from dxiv's comment: $r = (L-4x)/2\pi$, so $A$ depends only on $x$.  Now, you *don't* even need ([tag:derivatives]) to solve it.

Comment: But #r# is unknown, you can compute $r$ as $$r=\frac{y}{2\pi}$$

Comment: There is no reason for the $f(x)$ labels and it is confusing to label two different equations with the same label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You have $$A=x^2+\pi r^2$$ where $$r=\frac{y}{2\pi}$$ so we get

$$A=x^2+\frac{y^2}{4\pi}$$ Now we have the condintion: $$L=4x+y$$ with this equation we can eliminate $$y$$:

$$A(x)=x^2+\frac{1}{4\pi}(L-4x)^2$$
$$A'(x)=2x-\frac{8}{4\pi}(L-4x)$$ solving this we get

$$x=\frac{L}{4(\pi+4)}$$

and from here we get

$$y=L-4\frac{L}{4(\pi+4)}=L-\frac{L}{\pi+4}=\frac{L\pi}{\pi+4}$$

Comment: I think that works, thank you! And the value of $y$ would be this? $$y=\pi L$$

Comment: I have got $$y=\frac{L\pi}{\pi+1}$$

Comment: You are right. I forgot the denominator when solving the equation. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I wish you a good night!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I think there is something I am missing. You got this equation: $A=x^2+\frac{y^2}{4\pi}$, and found the value of $y$ from the other one (which is $y=(L-4x)$). Then you replaced it in the first equation, getting this: $$A(x)=4x^2+\frac{1}{4\pi}(L-4x)^2$$ But, where did the first 4 come from? Shouldn't it be like this? $$A(x)=x^2+\frac{1}{4\pi}(L-4x)^2$$

Comment: Oh sorry, this is a typo, since in Germany it is early in the morning. On my papersheet it is without the four!, sorry thousend times!

Comment: Don't worry. I just wanted to be sure. That's all and thank you so much once again!

Comment: Now i will go to bed, wish you a nice day (or night)!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Note that $L$ is a given value, so solve your second equation for one of the variables and plug that into the first equation.  That gives you $A$ as a function of the other variable.  Now take the derivative of $A$ with respect to that variable, set to zero....

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that we use $x$ units of wire for the square (so the side length is $x/4$) and $L-x$ units for the circle (so the radius is $\frac{L-x}{2\pi}$. Then the area can be expressed as
$$
A(x)=\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)^2+\pi\left(\frac{(L-x)}{2\pi}\right)^2\quad (0\leq x\leq L)
$$
Since $A$ is continuous and the domain is compact, a minimum exists. You can take it from  here.